# Fix rendered pgn boards so that they are the right size

Tags: feature-request

Boards made from the `pre` `code` section such as this:

`<pre><code>[fen ""] 1. f3 e5 2. g4 qh4</code></pre>`

now show up with a large amount of blank space beneath them. I see almost a full board size of empty space beneath the board now.

[image: Large Board]

This is on a windows 7 machine, using chrome 23, with a display resolution of 1048*764.

The reason is that there is a missing `css` definition which seems to have been accidentally removed.

Using `.moves {display: inline;}` will fix this issue.

[image: Normal Board]

Answer (score 2):

This is because the css class `moves` no longer has the definition "display:inline" which causes the `div` containing class `moves` to be rendered on the next line below the chess board and introduces a large amount of blank space.

If you want, you can use this code in your browser's url. Make sure that chrome doesn't remove the part that says `javascript:`

```
javascript:$('.moves').css('display','inline');
```

Just open one of the pages, put that in the url, hit enter, and the boards will be fixed.